# Keras individual cost function for every training sample depending on its input neurons

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I need to implement custom cost function with coefficients depending on input values of concrete training samples. Is it possible with Keras?

Background for a problem: I'm trying to implement quite simple neural network topology shown [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.7725.pdf) on 3rd page (heavy link).

upd:
Simplified example: given two input neurons IN1 and IN2, some hidden neurons and three output neurons OUT1, OUT2 and OUT3, calculate cost function for each training entry separately as
COST = IN1 * OUT1 + IN2*IN2*OUT2 + OUT3
(in other words, I need to get access to all input and output values to use different combinations of them)

Comment: I believe you have to add more detail to your question, what have you tried so far? What actual errors are you getting? Please rephrase your question so it is not so broad

Comment: Do you know the the coefficients or you need to calculate them? (If you need to calculate them, can you calculate them only with the input, or you need to calculate based on the output?)

Comment: Simplified example is added!